# Changing coordinates of Point geometry hides it

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-8

I am attempting to set a new coordinate for a Point geometry every second, but as soon as I set a new coordinate the geometry becomes invisible. I can see that the point geometry (feature) is still attached to the vector source, but it does not show.

What am I missing?

Source code: [React + OpenLayers](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-openlayers-forked-355gpr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import Feature from "ol/Feature";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import { Point } from "ol/geom";

export default () => {
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const trafficLayer = useRef();
  const aircraftPoint = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    aircraftPoint.current = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([113.89076390019189, 22.324364815058356]))
    });

    trafficLayer.current = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [aircraftPoint.current]
      })
    });

    new Map({
      target: mapRef.current,
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        }),
        trafficLayer.current
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([113.91, 22.32]),
        zoom: 14
      })
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const coordinates = [
      [12678261.843426304, 2550513.917829821],
      [12678276.389975028, 2550516.8934089835],
      [12678294.68746191, 2550522.6226611948],
      [12678310.736252038, 2550529.163896087],
      [12678321.009343857, 2550532.68416079],
      [12678341.116984975, 2550538.615152849],
      [12678352.285823219, 2550542.3976743887]
    ];

    let counter = 0;

    function moveAirplane() {
      console.log("Moving airplane: ", counter);

      const lonlat = fromLonLat([
        coordinates[counter][1],
        coordinates[counter][0]
      ]);
      aircraftPoint.current.getGeometry().setCoordinates(lonlat);

      if (counter + 1 > coordinates.length - 1) {
        counter = 0;
      } else {
        counter = counter + 1;
      }
    }

    let intervalId = setInterval(moveAirplane, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="map" ref={mapRef} />;
};
```

Comment: If you are calling `fromLonLat(coordinates[counter][1], coordinates[counter][0]])` the values supplied should be degrees (lon between -180 and +180, lat between -90 and +90) not values like 12678352,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct answer

The correct answer is explained by @Mike in his comments. You should use degree coordinates to make it work.

2. Re-factoring

This is not asked but the declaration following function should be reviewed:

> function moveAirplane()

Reason: The setInterval will trigger the useEffect every seconds, which will recreate the same function over and over. I think you should move it to higher scope. Here is my code review:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-openlayers-forked-qp4zw8

Continuing response to @JJY9 comment:
[image]

@JJY9, this is working as you mentioned because you've small environment (1 plane, and all known coordinates). For instance:

- Your program must ask coordinates to the plan (or validate ones)
- There are multiple plane with multiple coordinates to reload.

Comment: Hi, Just wish to know how is `function moveAirplane()` going to be recreated every time. The useEffect encapsulating it has got empty dependency array, which means it will only run once.I actually edited just the coordinates to lat long projections from the initially provided code, also removed frolLonLat and it worked

Comment: I tried to answer @JJY9.

Comment: Yes indeed in the case when there are multiple planes and moveAirplane is parameterized to take values from the parent function you would have to declare the function at a more higher scope that you can refer it easily.You are right if @OP's usecase is going to expand in the way we are thinking.  .